# How to get Escape char '\\\\' in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive

Can someone help to get  '\ \ \ \ ' (Four backshash) in my hive insert overwrite query output.

I tried:

```py
beeline = "beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2:blahblah'"
exportDir = " /dev/targetdir "
presql =  ' INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY \'' + exportDir + '\' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ' + 'ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' NULL DEFINED AS \'\' '
sql = " select abc from xyz limit 10 "

>>> print(beeline + " -e " + '\"'+ presql + sql+'\"')

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2blahblah' -e "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/dev/targetDir/' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' NULL DEFINED AS '' select abc from xyz limit 10"


#Expected O/p:

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2blahblah' -e "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/dev/targetDir/' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' NULL DEFINED AS '' select abc from xyz limit 10"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a raw string like this :

```py
slash_str = r"your_string_with_slashes"
```

Read more on raw strings here : [Link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 2):

In order to escape a single \, you need to use an extra \ as an escape character.  As such, to get what your expected output is, you would need to have 8 \ -- then each pair of the escape character plus the character to be escaped would display a single \.

Comment: Like this : a = " ESCAPED BY '\\\\\\\\'' "
print(a)
 ESCAPED BY '\\\\''

Comment: It worked. However raw string helped to remove other escape char too within same string. Thanks